# Add-on installation

Tags: add-on, installation, sverchok

I've searched all over the internet to find a **simple step by step** instructions on how to install Sverchok properly into blender. 
I did visit the official add-on repo's frontpage and tried to install the add-on like any other add on. I m trying to figure out what went wrong. What step did i miss? I see the add-on in my list but can NOT enable it. 
I am using blender 2.78C. Any help would be greatly  appreciated.

Comment: It is clearly stated at the [official addon repo's frontpage](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok), and you install it like any other addon in Blender. Requesting tutorials here is considered off topic.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos well, this makes a noob feel welcome ;-). Sorry maybe i should have given some more information. Yes i did visit the official add-on repo's frontpage. Yes i tried to install the add-on like any other add on. I m just trying to figure out what went wrong. What step did i miss. I see the add-on in my list but can NOT enable it. To me every answered question is like a little tutorial. As a newbie i have learned a lot so far thanks to the community. And I would like to continue learning and who knows maybe in the future i can help someone too.

Comment: There is nothing more to it that what you already did. If the addon can't be activated then something is wrong and should probably be reported to the addon author. Have you restarted Blender after installing? Blind guess: it is most likely a mismatch between Blender version, addon version, and/or maybe Python version

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the reply. I reinstalled blender 2.78c, don't know what went wrong but it's working fine now.

Comment: @David I found out what went wrong. A simple explanation; i was using a guest account in windows the add on was not visible. I logged in as an administrator and the add on is working and visible in blender.

Comment: @FunkY if that's what fixed the issue, then the same would happen with all add-ons not just Sverchok. Perhaps you might change the topic to be more inclusive of this fact.

Answer (score 4):

i'm one of the Sverchok developers.

There's nothing special about the installation of Sverchok. As suggested by the [readme](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok#installation), it is installed like any add-on. If you can install other add-ons then you know how to install Sverchok.

You mention in your comment that you resolved the installation issue by logging into windows as an administrator. I suspect you'd have similar failures during the installation of other add-ons.

Further technical questions about Sverchok can be asked on [our issue tracker](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues).